# Python JSON serialization for nested object

Tags: python, json

I have list of database records and I want to return this as JSON to the client.
The records are type of Employee object and should be grouped based on salary.

I have completed grouping this records. But I am not able to generate the preferred JSON format.

"SalaryEmployeeList" object is not JSON serializable.

Here the problem is "salary" and "employee_list" tag is missing.

**Python Objects:**

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, name, salary):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary        

    def toJson(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                          sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    def __repr__(self):
        self.toJson()

class SalaryEmployeeList:
    def __init__(self, salary, employee_list):
        self.salary = salary
        self.employee_list = employee_list

    def toJson(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                          sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    def __repr__(self):
        self.toJson()

1 Abi 5000  
2 Bal 6000
3 Con 8000
4 Den 5000
5 Eon 6000
6 Fun 8000
7 Gop 5000
8 Han 6000
9 Iyo 8000
10 John 5000
11 Kami 6000
```

**Required JSON format**

```
{
    {
      "salary": 5000,
      "employee_list": [
        {
          "name": "Abi",
          "id": 1          
        },
        {
          "name": "Den",
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "name": "Gop",
          "id": 7
        },
        {
          "name": "John",
          "id": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "salary": 6000,
      "employee_list": [
        {
          "name": "Bal",
          "id": 2          
        },
        {
          "name": "Eon",
          "id": 5
        },
        {
          "name": "Han",
          "id": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Kami",
          "id": 11
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "salary": 8000,
      "employee_list": [
        {
          "name": "Con",
          "id": 3          
        },
        {
          "name": "Fun",
          "id": 6
        },
        {
          "name": "Iyo",
          "id": 9
        }
      ]
    }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, JSON only supports a limited number of types. Your expected JSON structure will probably require you to write your own bespoke serialization/deserialization on top of JSON. Should be striaghtforward enough...

Comment: And ? What have you done to solve the problem exactly ? (except posting here). Obviously not much because a simple google search gives quite a few useful answers already...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers , I have added my points.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you will need to implement your own serialization logic. Furthermore, I hope the following code helps:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, name, salary):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def toJson(self):
        return json.dumps({'name': self.name, 'salary': self.salary}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.toJson()


class SalaryEmployeeList:
    def __init__(self, salary, employee_list):
        self.salary = salary
        self.employee_list = employee_list

    def toJson(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.toJson()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Employee(1, 'alice', 1000)
    b = Employee(2, 'bob', 2000)
    c = Employee(3, 'carl', 3000)
    employee_list = SalaryEmployeeList(0, [a, b, c])
    json_dictionary = json.loads(employee_list.toJson()) # dictionary loaded from JSON string
```